# I used tkinter that uses functions inside a while loop.how should I code the end of functions to return back to the while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

## there is no error but it doesn't return to while loop and repeats the task inside the function (adding 1 to correct answers or wrong answers) I also tried 'continue', and 'return' at the end of function.

```
while yes_r == 1 and condition1 is True: # the while loop


  for i in a:   # the iteration in which it uses texts
    b = int(i)
    if b == 2:   
       condition1 = False

    title= str(["is "+RA[b]+ Q[b]])

      
    if RA[b].strip() == A[b].strip():   
        res = True
    else:
        res = False
```

## repeats the task inside the function (adding 1 to correct answers or wrong answers each time that button is pressed)

```
    def Result_true(): # this is used for the first button
        global TrA
        global TQ
        global res  

        if res == True :

          TQ.set ( TQ.get ( ) + 1 )
          TrA.set ( TrA.get ( ) + 1 )
        else:
          TQ.set ( TQ.get ( ) + 1 )
                        # I add some codes here but I failed to succeed

    def Result_false(): # this is used for the second button and 
        
        global TrA
        global TQ
        global res   


        if res == True :
          TQ.set ( TQ.get ( ) + 1 )

        else:

          TQ.set ( TQ.get ( ) + 1 )
          TrA.set ( TrA.get ( ) + 1 )

#this section uses tkinter, I need to return back to the while loop after   
   #going into the functions via widgets

    b1 = Button(app02, text = " right!", width = 23, fg="green",command= Result_true).pack(side = 'right', padx = 0, pady = 0) 
    b2 = Button(app02, text = " wrong!", width = 23, fg="red", command=Result_false).pack(side = 'left', padx = 0, pady = 0)
```

Comment: What is it doing when you try it?  Does it have an error, does it hang, or do something forever?  Also, what are `s1` and `s2`?

Comment: no error. it doesn't come out of function, and do the function for ever.